# Error filtering Kendo UI grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to filter Kendo UI grid programatically but getting this error:

TypeError: "".toLowerCase is not a function

Below is the code which I am using to filter grid:

```js
function filterSavedTransactions(checkboxstate,grid,field1,field2,amount)
     {
         if (!parseFloat(amount))
             amount = 0;
            
         if (checkboxstate) {

             var ds = $('#' + grid.attr('id')).data("kendoGrid").dataSource;

             ds.filter([{
                 "logic":"and",
                 filters: [
                    {
                        field: field2,
                        operator: "gt",
                        value: amount
                    },
                    {
                        field: field1,
                     operator: "neq",
                     value: checkboxstate
                    }]
             }]);
         }
         else {
             $('#' + grid.attr('id')).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
         }
     }
```

I am referring to below link and doing in the same way but not working on my side.

http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/MG89G/

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in this piece of code? I cannot see anything relating to your type error here

Comment: Yes, I am sure as this function is used to filter records.

Comment: Can you show the piece of code where that function is called

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, I made changes in code and it fixed the issue. What I did is that I replaced line of code : value: amount with value: parseFloat(amount) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too.  Adding the numeric columns to the dataSource schema didn't fix it.

Adding `type: 'number'` to the column definition didn't fix it either.

What finally worked for me was to `parseInt()` the filter text and change my operator from 'contains' to 'eq.'

Answer (score 0):

Kendo seems to like fields to be cast. I had to add:

```
template: function (dataItem) {
    return kendo.toString(dataItem.FriendlyStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked from me too Thanks Ebbs

```
columns: [
        {
            field: "MyFieldNameWhichisInteger", title: "My Field Name", width: "200px",
             filterable: {
                extra: false,
                operators: {
                    string: {
                        startswith: "Starts with",
                        eq: "Is equal to",
                        neq: "Is not equal to"
                    }
                },
                cell: {
                    operator: "eq",
                    suggestionOperator: "eq"
                }
            },
            template: function (dataItem) {
                return kendo.toString(dataItem.MyFieldNameWhichisInteger);
            }

        }
```